# Click not work in a Div in excel slicer in Mobile mode in sharepoint 2013

Tags: android, jquery, excel, mobile, sharepoint

I have a Div in Excel. This Div is a Excel Slicer. When I click in one of it's rows in mobile mode, touchstart raised but only that row will be highlighted and nothing else.
excel slicer is something like this : 
[image: Image1]

You can see I click on slicer but it is only highlighted and click not raise.
EWAMoss.js is main Js.
any help would be help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the master file to handle slicers it's called `SlicerRendererControl.ascx`

The address where it can be found is:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\SlicerRendererControl.ascx`

I've changed this file to

```
<%-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. --%>

<%@ Register Tagprefix="ewa" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.Internal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ Control Language="C#" CompilationMode=Never Inherits="Microsoft.Office.Excel.WebUI.SlicerRendererControl" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

        <style type="text/css"> <!-- <asp:Literal RunAt="server" ID="m_slicerStyle"/> --> </style>
        <link RunAt="server" ID="m_ewrCss"/>
        <link RunAt="server" ID="m_slicersCss"/>
    </head>
    <body style="padding:0; margin:0;" tabIndex="-1" behjat="n">
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:Panel class="ewr-slicer-body" id="m_slicerContainer" RunAt="server" role="main">

                <div class="ewr-slicer-background">


                    <div class="ewr-slicer-margin">

                        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" runat="server" id="m_containerTabStop" class="ewr-slicer-contents-tab-stop" tabIndex="2" role="gridcell" aria-live="polite" />
                        <div class="ewr-slicer-item-container ewa-scrollbars" tabindex="-1">
                            <div class= "Moghimi" >
                                <asp:Panel RunAt="server" ID="m_slicerPushDiv"/> 
                                <asp:Table RunAt="server" ID="m_slicerContents"/>
                                <asp:Panel RunAt="server" ID="m_slicerEmptyNotification"/>
                                <asp:Panel RunAt="server" ID="m_slicerPullDiv"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ewr-slicer-caption">
                    <div class="ewr-slicer-caption-margin">
                        <asp:Panel RunAt="server" ID="m_slicerChevron"/>
                        <asp:Panel RunAt="server" ID="m_slicerCaption" />
                        <asp:Panel RunAt="server" ID="m_slicerHeaderButton"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <asp:Panel class="ewa-background-disabled ewr-slicer-whitebox" RunAt="server" ID="m_background" />
                <div class="ewr-slicer-notification">
                    <div class="ewr-slicer-notification-margin">
                        <asp:Panel RunAt="server" ID="m_slicerUpdateCaption">
                            <asp:Literal id="m_caption" runat="server"/>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel RunAt="server" ID="m_slicerUpdateButton">
                            <asp:Button id="m_update" runat="server"/>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                <asp:Literal RunAt="server" ID="m_slicerScript"/>
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function touchHandler(event)
                {
                    var touches = event.changedTouches;                
                    var first = touches[0];
                    var type = "";
                    switch(event.type)
                    {
                        case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
                        case "touchmove":  type = "mousemove"; break;        
                        case "touchend":   type = "mouseup";   break;
                        default:           return;
                    }                   
                    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
                    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1, 
                                                  first.screenX, first.screenY, 
                                                  first.clientX, first.clientY, false, 
                                                  false, false, false, 0, null);

                    first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
                    event.preventDefault();

                };
                var slicersContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("Moghimi");
                var slicerContainer = slicersContainer[0];
                slicerContainer.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);  
                slicerContainer.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
                slicerContainer.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
                slicerContainer.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true); 
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```